# Collinearity in isosceles trapeze

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let ABCD be an isosceles trapeze with $AB||CD$, $AB=12$, $CD=8$ and $m(\angle ABC)=60$. The parallel to $AC$ through $B$ intersects $CD$ in $P$, $Q$ is the middle point of $AB$ and $G$ is on $BC$ such that $BG=\frac{BC}3$.

The problem asks me to prove that $m(\angle ADC)=120$, which is simple because the trapeze is isosceles, and that the points $P$, $G$ and $Q$ are collinear, which I can't seem to be able to figure out. I made the following figure to represent this situation:

[image]

I have computed the values of $BG$ and $QG$ hoping that perhaps the angle $QGB$ has a nice value (since from the figure it kind of looks like it's 90 degrees), but that doesn't seem to be the case. The only solution that I can see it through using coordinates, but that seems quite tedious, moreover I'm not supposed to use it here.

I also considered the point G' as the middle of BC, in which case both QG and PG would be medians of a triangle. This doesn't seem to get me anywhere though.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be the intersection point of $CA$ with $PQ$.

Also, let $F$ be the intersecion point of $PE$ with $BC$.

Then, we see that $AE=PB$.

Since $\triangle{FPB}$ and $\triangle{FEC}$ are similar, we have
$$FB:FC=PB:EC=PB:2PB=1:2$$
from which we see that $F=G$.

So, the three points $P, G$ and $Q$ are collinear.